# How can I rewrite the Google Sheet formula to make it autofill without hand dragging?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, string-formatting, textjoin

I have only given data A & B 2 columns and want to create column C to concatenate column A & B with autofill function. How can I rewrite the C1 formula to make it?
[image]

Any thoughts? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={"PK"; ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(B2:B, "yyyy-m-dd")&A2:A)}
```

or just:

```
={"PK"; ARRAYFORMULA(B2:B&A2:A)}
```